# Ionic Angular: Saving to todo items to a list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I need `*ngModel` help because as I change the `ion-input` field, the contents of the list change accordingly.

First I type "hello", then I start to delete it to make room for another todo item but the 'todo list' changes. Please see pictures, thank you!

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Can you please add the code of your question. ( The HTML of the component and the controller )

Comment: Please update code and provide your accepted result

Comment: And could you please make the images smaller... (Remove the white background) because it's really annoying to scroll down there.

Comment: @Rankia_Nisal Aloha thanks

Comment: @Utpaul Aloha thanks

Comment: @FranzHuber23 Aloha thanks!